# Use string length as parameter in pyspark.sql substring function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to use the Spark sql `substring` function to get a substring from a string in one column row while using the length of a string in a second column row as a parameter.

How do I do this?

The following set-up is reproducible.

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()    

df = spark.createDataFrame([('prefix body suffix','suffix',)], ['a', 'b',])
```

Problem function returns `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`:

```py
df = df.withColumn('noSuffix',
        F.substring(
            str = F.col('a'),
            pos = 1,
            len = F.length('a') - F.length('b')))
```

The following works, but I still can't use the resulting integer in the `substring` function.

```py
df = df.withColumn('length', F.length('a') - F.length('b'))
```

Same problem using `substring_index` function.

```py
df = df.withColumn('outCol',
        F.substring_index( 
            F.col('a'),
            F.col('b'),
            1))
```

Is there a way to do this without creating an rdd function, then using `df.rdd.map(rddFunction).toDF()` ?

Comment: See the dupe I linked for how to do this using `pyspark.sql.functions.expr`. However, if you're just trying to remove the string in `b` from `a`, you could also use `regexp_replace`.

Comment: ok, this works: `df = df.select('a','b', F.expr("substring(a, 1, (length(a) - length(b)) )").alias('noSuffix'))`.  Although, not very intuitive or pretty considering all the `F.`'s and other quotes around col names have to be removed.  This is an oversimplified example of my real problem and `regexp_replace` wont do. Thanks.